# ERROR: AlreadyExistsError - Cannot exceed quota for PoliciesPerRole: 10

Tags: python-3.x

Im using awsebcli(*pip install awsebcli —upgrade —user)
for build NLB (NetWork Load Balancer) on elasticbeanstalk with awsebcli(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli/3.0.3)

But I have a problem now.....

```
$ eb create
Enter Environment Name
(default is ko-dev-dev): 
Enter DNS CNAME prefix
(default is ko-dev-dev):
```

and then

```
Select a load balancer type
1) classic
2) application
3) network
(default is 1): 3


**ERROR: AlreadyExistsError - Cannot exceed quota for PoliciesPerRole: 10**
```

I wonder what is causing this problem now . . . . .

```
requirements.txt

awscli==1.14.31
awsebcli==3.12.1
blessed==1.14.2
botocore==1.8.35
cement==2.8.2
colorama==0.3.7
docker-py==1.7.2
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.14
jmespath==0.9.3
pathspec==0.5.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.9.1
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.12
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
tabulate==0.7.5
termcolor==1.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.46.0
```

Comment: According to five seconds of googling, AWS puts some limits here and there, so probably you need to contact the AWS support

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are some limits for resources in AWS.

So suppose you want to increase that limit,

Just go to

Service Quotas --> Aws Services --> IAM --> Raise a ticket

e.g

[image]

Note: For IAM quotas to increase, you need to select the region US East (N. Virginia)

For More details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html